# How do I delete empty rows in excel but not empty cells in rows with information in them?

Tags: macos, mac, ms-office

I am working with a large excel spreadsheet and I need to delete all the rows that are completely blank.

I do not want to delete rows or cells with any information in any of the columns.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I am assuming is that you have a large worksheet with gaps you need to close up, and that a simple sort would disrupt the order of your data.

Here's how I would do it: First add two new temporary columns, new A and new B. Select the range of cells in A from the first all the way to the last row you know has data. Use Edit > Fill > Series > Linear and number them from 1 to whatever.

In the next column select the first cell and enter a formula that checks to see if the cells to its right are empty. It could be as simple as adding them all up (`=SUM(C1:K1)`) to see if they are zero or it could be a function of logic (`=AND(ISBLANK(C1), ISBLANK(D1))`, etc.). Copy and paste this formula down all the cells in column B to the end of your range.

Now you have two keys with which to sort your worksheet. Sort on column B to find your empty rows and delete them en masse, then restore your worksheet's original sort order by sorting on the first column.

Answer (score 4):

If you only want to delete rows that are completely empty, the easiest way I've found is to use a filter.  Highlight all of the columns that you want to include and then click the filter button.  Uncheck "select all", and then scroll to the very bottom and click to check the box for blanks.  This will show only your blank rows.  Highlight all and right-click a row and select delete.  This deleted all your blank rows.  Now turn off the filter and viola, no blank rows!

Answer (score 1):

insert a new column and count blank cells in a row: =COUNTBLANK(C8:R8)
use this to pull down to all interested rows.

say you are looking at 20 columns.. then whatever row gets 20 blank cells is a row to delete. Later on you can get rid of this column u used for testing.